# Convergence in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I wish to understand how to cope with the following error messages:

```
k = 0.5;
λ = 0.4;
W[t_] := (E^(-t/λ)) ((t)^(k - 1)) GammaRegularized[0.5`, 2.5` t] GammaRegularized[1.5`, 7.5` t]
F[τ_] := NIntegrate[E^((-3 - I 0.16 ) t) W[t] , {t, 0, τ}, MaxRecursion -> 50]
F[∞]
```

> During evaluation of In[113]:= NIntegrate::deodiv: DoubleExponentialOscillatory returns a finite integral estimate, but the integral might be divergent. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[113]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[113]:= NIntegrate::deorel: The relative error ComplexInfinity is larger than expected for the integrand -(((0. +1. I) E^(-5.5 (0. +t)) GammaRegularized[0.5,2.5 (0. +t)] GammaRegularized[1.5,7.5 (0. +t)] Sin[0.16 t])/(0. +t)^0.5) over {0,[Infinity]} with DoubleExponentialOscillatory method and tuning parameters, TuningParameters -> {10,5}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[113]:= NIntegrate::deoncon: DoubleExponentialOscillatory has failed to converge for the integrand -(((0. +1. I) E^(-5.5 (0. +t)) GammaRegularized[0.5,2.5 (0. +t)] GammaRegularized[1.5,7.5 (0. +t)] Sin[0.16 t])/(0. +t)^0.5) over {0,[Infinity]}. DoubleExponentialOscillatory obtained 0. -0.00207921 I and ComplexInfinity for the integral and error estimates. >>

```
(* 0.408534 - 0.00207501 I*)
```

While it seems clear that the integral converges quite fast:

```
Plot[{Re[F[t]], Im[F[t]]}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Perhaps I should change the integration method, but I do not have clue on how to proceed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbolic processing is finding a high frequency oscillatory function. Let's just process the thing numerically:

```
F[τ_] := NIntegrate[E^((-3 - I 0.16) t) W[t], {t, 0, τ}, 
                    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
F[∞]

(* 0.408534 - 0.00207501 I *)
```

Comment: Exponential factor should be `E^((-3 - I 16/100)`

Comment: Thanks! could you also suggest why exact arithmetic is necessary?

Comment: @BobHanlon You're right, thanks!. With that change my old answer stopped working. This new one does work.